Comparative structure
Can we just say 'She is more beautiful.'
Instead of 'She is more beautiful than I (am).'?
And is than I (am). a complement or modifier here?

You need to put more effort into composing your questions. You need to tell us what has led you to ask the question in terms of confusion over some theory or model, what you think the answer is and why, or why you question there even being a clear answer. It is unseemly to expect people to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking the question. What research did you do where, and what did you find? What are your own guesses and why?


Can we just say 'She is more beautiful.'
Instead of 'She is more beautiful than I (am).'?

Yes, you can as long as there's context. For example: 
A: You're beautiful.
B: She's more beautiful (than I am/than me).

And is than I (am). a complement or modifier here?

First, either than I am or than me is more idiomatic than than I. Second, it is a complement. If you're wondering how a complement can be omitted without changing the meaning, it can. There's no absolute requirement that complements not be omissible.
But the distinction between a complement and a modifier depends on how you define these terms, so you may get different answers from different people depending on what kind of grammar they follow.
My answer is based on H&P's CGEL.
